# It is possible to call class function from outside class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call function outside from class and update the state of class. Is this correct way ?

```
    function  myFunc() {
       this.Test("test")
    }

    class Notification extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            demoState:''
        };
      }

      Test(data){

       this.setState({
           demoState:data 
         })
      }

      render(){
         return(<div/>)
      }
}
```

Comment: If you need to update state of a component from within another component you should send the method as props or use state management library like Redux. Sending ‘this’ around will male your codebase become a nighmare to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided function usage in your example.

It's correct way, that's how the most function works. But don't tease react.js by using `this` argument - just pass an argument to `myFunc`

Answer (score 0):

**YES** pass `this` an argument to myFunc.

```
function  myFunc(this /* <----- */) {
   this.Test("test")
}
```

Then call myFunc from inside of class like this:

```
myFunc(this);
```

Comment: Throwing ‘this’ around like this isn’t very good idea I think. I would rather use .call() (or .apply()).

Answer (score 0):

May be, you need to pass object of that class to change the state. Have a look at myFunc & Notification.Test function changes.

```
function myFunc() {
  let notification = new Notification({});
  notification.Test("test");
  console.log(notification.state);
}

class Notification extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      demoState: ''
    };
  }

  Test(data) {

    this.state = {
      demoState: data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return ('<div/>')
  }
}
```